# pdo select column from $_POST

Tags: php, pdo

In my database I have a table called user_items where I store each username and how many of each item they have. I have 1 column for each and every time the user can buy and a column for their username. Now I also have an HTML form and want to do a PDO select from the HTML select.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['Detach'])) {

    // Here we get the info about the pokemon
    $teamget = $db->prepare("select * from user_items where username = :name");
    $teamget->execute(array(':name' =>  $_SESSION['username']));
    $getteam = $teamget->fetch(); // Use fetchAll() if you want all results, or just iterate over the statement, since it implements Iterator

    echo $getteam -> $_POST['item'];

    echo "working";
}
?>

<form method="post" action="">

    <select name="item" id="item" style="width:150px;padding-left:5px;">
        <option value=""></option>     
        <option>poke_ball</option>
        <option>great_ball</option>
        <option>ultra_ball</option>
        <option> aster_ball</option>
        <option>potion</option>
        <option>super_potion</option>
        <option>hyper_potion</option>
        <option>burn_heal</option>
        <option>parlyz_heal</option>
        <option>antidote</option>
        <option>awakening</option>
        <option>ice_heal</option>
        <option>dawn_stone</option>
        <option>dusk_stone</option>
        <option>fire_stone</option>
        <option>leaf_stone</option>
        <option>moon_stone</option>
        <option>oval_stone</option>
        <option>shiny_stone</option>
        <option>sun_stone</option>
        <option>thunder_stone</option>
        <option>water_stone</option>
        <option>exp_share</option>
    </select>

    <select name="Detach" id="Detach" style="width:150px;padding-left:5px;">
        <option value=""></option>      
        <option>Attach To Pokemon 1</option>
        <option> Attach To Pokemon 2</option>
        <option> Attach To Pokemon 3</option>
        <option> Attach To Pokemon 4</option>
        <option> Attach To Pokemon 5</option>
        <option> Attach To Pokemon 6</option>

?>
     </select>
     <br/>
     <br/>

     <br/>
     <br/>
     <button name="submit" type="submit" id="Submit_Butt">Detach Item</button>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
     <p>&nbsp;</p>
 </form>
```

The first select is the name of each column. What I'm trying to do is select the value of the column where `$_POST` = the column

Would this work ?

```
$teamget = $db->prepare("select '".$_POST['item']."' from user_items where username = :name");
$teamget->execute(array(':name' =>  $_SESSION['username']));
$getteam = $teamget->fetch(); // Use fetchAll() if you want all results, or just iterate over the statement, since it implements Iterator

echo $getteam ;
```

Comment: `session_start();` is undoubtedly in there, correct?

Comment: Yep and the $db connect

Comment: Knew it. SO newbies always leave that bit of information out.

Comment: I always put the session start and db connect at the top of the page.

Comment: Which is good, however whenever the word $_SESSION comes into play and `session_start();` is not included nor mentioned, it's the first question I ask. You know it's in there, but we/I don't. ;-) just *"food for thought"*

Comment: couldn;t i put the post in side the pdo select ? Ill edit my first post to show what i mean

Answer (score 0):

Your table organized wrong way. What it have to be:

```
username item quantity
```

and now you can query it this way

```
$sql  ="select quantity from user_items where username = ? and item = ?";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array($_SESSION['username'], $_POST['item']));
$item = $stmt->fetchColumn();

echo $item;
```

it's also ought to be `user_id` and `item_id` in this table instead of actual names, but it is already too complex for you

Comment: **Your table organized wrong way. You need another table structure to store your data**

Comment: So i have column names for the item names so i want to do a simple select form were the item match the column. So i could have a column called item1 so if i wanted to get the amount of item 1's they have i want to do a select were username = username and column = item1 which is stored in the post

Comment: **You shouldn't have a column called item1**. I can understand when someone is going to use a database having no knowledge on using them. But I don't understand when someone refuse to use a database properly when told so.

Comment: Because my whole site is bases around that table so if i remove the table the site will fall.